# Нужны ли индексы для LIKE - MySql?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени..

В базе 800 тыс.записей . Поиск по слову-(вам) работает туго .
Выборка идет по полям

```
..... and ( advert.text LIKE '%тест%' or advert.name_adv LIKE '%тест%' or advert.key_words LIKE '%тест%' )
```

Подскажите, нужно ли добавлять индексы для трех этих колонок  (для основных колонок добавлены ранее и работа ускорилась) ?

Если да, то какие : составные или по отдельности или выборочно из трех ?

Answer (score 3):

Обычные индексы для запроса типа LIKE '%word%' бессмысленны, всё равно не будут использоваться. Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону полнотекстовых индексов.

Comment: @Akinaне надо быть таким категоричным, ты ж видел, что в 5.7 Like использует индексы

Comment: Нет, не видел. Максимум что я видел - это факты, позволяющие предположить, что 5.7 вместо table fullscan научился делать index fullscan + index merge. И то при условии что индекс ещё не вымылся из кэша.

Comment: тогда придется поверить EXPLAIN .... на sql.ru я показывал.

Comment: Если LIKE начинается с шаблона %, то индекс не используется. Если с символа 'Word%' - используется